# ypinit -m errors

Tags: linux, nis

I am trying to set up a ypmaster.

Step 1 cd /var/yp

At the start this was an EMPTY directory (important later)

Step 2, type: "/usr/lib64/yp/ypinit -m

Now this directory has lots of files.

Step 3 I try to setup some files.

Step 4 Meaning: customize (Edit the files)

Step 5 - unsure at this stage
Goal was:
I wanted to disable YPPASSWD - we use AD
I wanted to disable YPGROUPs again we use AD
I do not want to use YP for these things.

Step 6 - intention was to
Just erase and make that directory empty again.
Then re-run: ypinit -m again?

And this is where I am stuck.

It does not create the "Makefile"
or the other files/directories.

I want to "reset" or "force" ypinit.
Since ypinit is a shellscript other potential issues may arise.
I do not see where the Makefile came from.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh....I'm confused, you are setting up YP/NIS services but you want really to use LDAP/AD?  You'll need to add a lot more information explaining what you really want to do here.

Comment: A) I figured out my problem - I had to reinstall the YP tools. Doing that - updated/replaced the makefile (B) The IT DEPT wants to manage username/group/passwords via Active Directory [by policy].  What I need is some means to share/distribute a MAP for the auto mounter so that various Linux machines can properly auto mount exports from various servers from a COMMON place - A longtime ago (SunOS they used YP for this and it worked nicely, so that is my point of reference)